# Unitary transformation: order of $U^{\dagger}$ and $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, linear-transformations

If $U$ is a unitary matrix and $U^{\dagger} A U$ a unitary transformation, then also $U A U^{\dagger}$ is a unitary transformation. But are $U^{\dagger} A U$ and $U A U^{\dagger}$ necessarily equal in the general case?

Comment: What's  a unitary transformation?

Comment: @ArcticChar It's the complex analogy of an orthogonal transformation. The $\dagger$ represents the complex conjugate transpose (as opposed to just the transpose for real matrices). Unitary matrices are length-preserving and satisfy $U^\dagger U = I$.

Comment: I am just confused since they used both unitary matrix and unitary transformation. @paulinho I though that might be different.

Comment: @ArcticChar Ah ok. I think they're used interchangeably here

Comment: What I meant was that $U$ is the matrix used to carry out the unitary transformation of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$
U=\pmatrix{0&-1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&1},
A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&1&0},
U^\ast AU=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&1&0\\ 1&0&0},
UAU^\ast=\pmatrix{0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\ -1&0&0}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

No, all this implies is that $A$ is also unitary. One way to see why they don't have to be equal is simply by multiplying one by the other's inverse:
$$(U^\dagger A U) (U A U^\dagger)^\dagger = U^\dagger A U^2 A^\dagger U^\dagger$$
which certainly need not be the identity for any similar unitary matrices $A$ or $U$. See user1551's explicit counterexample.

Comment: Sorry I'm not upvoting, but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks for the answer.